# Overflow hidden property won't work

Tags: css, overflow, hidden

Here's the code, it's outside of the container. For some reason I can't fathom the element won't hide. Is there some kind of a conflict between the properties?

```
#header2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 71px;
    left: 0%;
    margin-left: -906px;
    width: 2831px;
    height: 56px;
    background:url("images/header2.gif") no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`visiblity: hidden;` or `display: none;`

With *visibility*, you'll hide the element, but it will still alter DOM display, where, *display* will completely hide element, with behavior like it would've been removed.

**Edit:**
Huh, well, in that case, you should look at [100% height fix/sticky footer/whatever you name it](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) and add `overflow: hidden;` to your *container*. Because of that, you should add your `#header2` element as a child of *container*. Plus, add `position: relative;` to *container* so `#header2` absolute position is calculated from *container*.

Actually, in this case, your *container* will be the new `body`, that's why you should add `overflow` to it, and make `#header2` as a child.

Ofcourse, if your site isn't vertically expanding, then you could get through with adding just `overflow: hidden;` property to your `body` tag.

All that hassle is because `overflow` property hides inner content that overflows element dimensions. Basically, overflow works like crop.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, but let me rephrase myself. This is a graphic element. It's supposed to be shown, not hidden. The element is gigantic and it makes the scrolling bar to appear on the bottom, which is the problem. I need to hide the overflow, so that in different screen resolutions the graphic element would cover the whole width, again, without the horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer you are looking for is `display: none`?